# Saving expanded state of JTree when adding elements to nodes

Tags: java, swing, jtree, defaulttreemodel

Hello I have question regarding saving expansion state when change DefaultTreeModel. Currently I have a jTree which looks like this:
[image]

If I select an item from the left JList and select a TestGr from right Jtree and click on Add Test Case button it will add the selected items to the DefaultTreeModel. Doing this will collapse the tree: 
[image]

I would like to somehow save the previous expansion state and just update the tree to show the newly added element like this for example: 
[image]

My goal is to save the previously expanded state which ever that may be and when I add elements to TestGr, everything which was expanded, should stay expanded and update itself with the new element. Does anyone have any idea how might i achieve this? I have tried the solution from [store state/expanded nodes of a jtree for restoring state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878959/store-state-expanded-nodes-of-a-jtree-for-restoring-state) but it's not suitable because when i update my DefaultTreeModel, the row count gets updated too and it expands the wrong rows. Thank you in advance for a hint.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) of your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use DefaultTreeModel reload method, but for a specific node.
for Example:

```
DefaultTreeModel model;
DefaultMutableTreeNode node;
//Initialize or change model
model.reload(node);
enter code here
```